# Gatsby plugin settings for gatsby-plugin-postcss + autoprefixer + browserslist

Tags: css, cross-browser, gatsby, postcss, autoprefixer

My goal is to have `gatsby-plugin-postcss` set all the browser prefixes for my CSS file during `gatsby build`. From the docs, the preferred way is to use browserslist, and use autoprefixer with postcsss during the gatsby build process.

My `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const browserslist = require('browserslist');

module.exports = {
  },
  plugins: [
    // `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
      options: {
        postCssPlugins: [
          autoprefixer({ browsers: browserslist() }),
        ],
      },
  ],
};
```

package.json:

```
  // ...
  "browserslist": ["defaults"]
```

I get this warining:

> warn
> Replace Autoprefixer browsers option to Browserslist config.
> Use browserslist key in package.json or .browserslistrc file.
>
> Using browsers option can cause errors. Browserslist config
> can be used for Babel, Autoprefixer, postcss-normalize and other tools.
>
> If you really need to use option, rename it to overrideBrowserslist.
>
> Learn more at:
> https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#readme
> https://twitter.com/browserslist

The HTML shows that no prefixes were set.

This configuration worked (as in the build files contained browser prefixes) but it still complains that I do not use browserlist:

```
{
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    options: {
      postCssPlugins: [
        autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'not ie 10'],
          grid: true,
        })
      ],
    },
}
```

What is the correct plugin options configurations so the autoprefixer takes my browserslist?

Answer (score 2):

In my gastby-config.js file

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssAspectRatio = require('postcss-aspect-ratio');


{
     resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
     options: {
         postCssPlugins: [
             autoprefixer(),
             postcssAspectRatio
         ],
     },
 },
```

I have a separate .browserslistrc file for browser options.
Check your dependencies, but a separate install of browserlist npm shouldn't be required.